# "In a trick" is this correctly used in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

I am wondering if this is grammatical.

> The branch was moved with a stick by foreign agents **in a trick/wheeze**, which distracted the American agents and allowed to sneak inside the house.

Is it the right preposition, or should you use a different preposition than "in".

Comment: It doesn't say _who_ was allowed to sneak into the house!

Comment: If moving the branch was part of a trick/scheme/ploy/tactical strategy (I’m personally not sure of what you mean by wheeze), then this sentence would be correct.

Comment: Your sentence doesn't make sense. You're missing who was allowed to sneak into the house. You're also using phrases that need to be explained, as they are not idioms.